# Capturing server event logs in Seq

Tags: seq, event-viewer, server-error, seq-logging

I'm looking at installing Seq to view all my application exceptions in one place. This is easy to do for exceptions in my C# code, by using Serilog. However, I would like to send server event logs to Seq as well (that is, the events that show up in Event Viewer). How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

At present, there's no Event Log → Serilog or Event Log → Seq bridge that I'm aware of.

You can tail event logs in C# and pipe them through Serilog using [`EventLog.EntryWritten`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.eventlog.entrywritten.aspx), if this approach is an option for you.